# How does Haskell determine what kind of boolean a randomly generated number is?

Tags: haskell, random

Consider the following two groups of code:

```
random (mkStdGen 1) :: (Int, StdGen) 
-- returns (7918028818325808681,545291967 2103410263)
random (mkStdGen 1) :: (Bool, StdGen) 
-- returns (True,80028 40692)


random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Int, StdGen) 
-- returns (9159618695640234475,587416689 2103410263)
random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Bool, StdGen)
-- returns (False,1485632275 40692)
```

Why does `7918028818325808681` translate to `True` but `9159618695640234475` translates to `False`?

Comment: The question is based on a faulty premise: the implementation of `random` for `Bool` need not (and does not) call the implementation of `random` for `Int`.

Comment: I am basing my example code on a tutorial series called "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!". As I am a beginner, I wouldn't even know my premise is faulty

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the output to be, and why?

Comment: The premise is not really faulty: A `RandomGen` produces `Int`’s (see `next`), and the other instances are built on that.

Comment: @user38352 That's why Daniel Wagner is telling you that. He's not saying "gosh you should have known better", but "the behavior you noticed doesn't have the cause that you guessed it did". Clearly you couldn't know by yourself that the premise was faulty, but now that you've been told, you do. Hurrah, learning for everyone.

Comment: For what it's worth, this isn't a property of Haskell, but a property of the implementation of the `random` package, separate from the base module.

Comment: @DanielWagner, Could you provide an example of how `random` is implemented for `Bool`?

Comment: @user38352 The answer you accepted includes the complete source for the `random @Bool`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Instance Bool` shares the implementation with `Instance Int`, but the code that is shared is the one for `randomR`, which takes a range. We can verify this using QuickCheck:

```
Prelude> import Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> import System.Random
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random> :{
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random| prop seed = let
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random|   gen = mkStdGen seed
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random|   b = fst (random gen)
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random|   i = fst (randomR (0,1) gen)
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random|  in if b then i == 1 else i == 0
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random| :}
Prelude Test.QuickCheck System.Random> quickCheck prop
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

You can also look at the [definition of the `instance Random Bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#instance%20Random%20Bool) where you will find this code:

```
instance Random Bool where
  randomR (a,b) g = 
      case (randomIvalInteger (bool2Int a, bool2Int b) g) of
        (x, g') -> (int2Bool x, g')
       where
         bool2Int :: Bool -> Integer
         bool2Int False = 0
         bool2Int True  = 1

     int2Bool :: Int -> Bool
     int2Bool 0 = False
     int2Bool _ = True

  random g    = randomR (minBound,maxBound) g
```

so essential, you are calling `randomR (0,1)` and then mapping `0` to `False` and `1` to `True`:

```
> random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Bool, StdGen)
(False,1485632275 40692)
> randomR (0,1) (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Int, StdGen)
(0,1485632275 40692)
> random (mkStdGen 1) :: (Bool, StdGen)
(True,80028 40692)
> randomR (0,1) (mkStdGen 1) :: (Int, StdGen)
(1,80028 40692)
```